# Datagram Channel vs Data gram Socket vs Ayschronous datagram channel?

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, networking, java-8

- What are the main differences between Datagram Channel and Datagram
  socket ?
- How they differ with AyschronousDatagram channel differ with above
  two ?
- Why "AyschronousDatagramChannel" class is not available in java 8?

(Use case : UDP sever which only receives a single UDP packet which should be logged to mysql database (no need of response))

Comment: If `AsynchronousDatagramChannel` doesn't exist why are you asking about it?

Comment: @EJP Class existed in java 7 and cannot find in later versions, found this http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6993126,  article which explains why it is removed, but my question is about , what could be theory behind of not requiring such class :)?